# Is it good to keep dictionary database files on internal storage in android?

Tags: android, internal-storage, jaws-wordnet

I have successfully accessed WordNet dictionary data files on external storage using JAWS APIs. But now I want to keep these files on internal storage in order to make them private to my app. The dictionary files are about 35MB in size. My question is, **Is it possible or good practice to use internal storage for this purpose and to keep a file as large as 35MB on it?** 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes definitely you can but you should not.

From the [compatibility definition for Android 6.0](http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/source.android.com/en/us/compatibility/android-6.0-cdd.pdf)

Device implementations(Android phone) MUST have at least 424 of non-volatile storage available for user data. That is, the /data partition MUST be at least 424mb.

Which mean all app can store internal data upto 424 mb. But keeping database scale and older os (lesser space) in consideration i would not suggest to store 35 mb data internally.

Comment: Thank you so much. But this 424MBs limit doesn't make any sense, does it?

Comment: it depends upon device manufacturer most of the mobile have around 1gb now a days.